# angularjs conditionally uneditable checkbox with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a set of checkboxes with ng-repeat. They should be checked by default. So, in controller, I have set a property

```
self.select_all_tc=true;
```

Among the checkboxes, there are some items that should be checked by default, but should not be unchecked at any time. There is also a "Select All" button, that selects/unselects all the checkboxes.

```
<div class="card-body" ng-show="selectuc">
    <label>Select All: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctlr.select_all_tc"  ></label><br/>
    <md-table-container >
    <table  md-table multiple md-progress="promise">
        <tr >
            <th ><span>Test Case Name</span></th>
            <th ><span>Test Case Description</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in ctlr.tasklist | filter:{SHOW_IN_UI:'!FALSE'}">
            <td >
                <input id="{{task.NAME}}"  type="checkbox" 
                       ng-checked= "ctlr.select_all_tc"
                       ng-disabled="task.MANDATORY=='TRUE'"/>
                <input id="{{task.NAME}}"  type="checkbox"
                       ng-checked= "ctlr.select_all_tc"
                       ng-disabled="task.MANDATORY=='TRUE'"/>
                {{ task.NAME }}
            </td>
            <td >{{ task.DESCRIPTION }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </md-table-container>
</div>
```

My problem is this: Upon unchecking "Select All", it unchecks the mandatory-uneditable checkbox too. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Have you tried `ng-checked= "ctlr.select_all_tc || task.MANDATORY=='TRUE'"` ?